# Get peaks with the same height

Tags: python, computer-vision

I have the following spectrum that I got from using a vertical histogram of an image.

1) I would like to get the peaks with the same height as shown in the figure with red arrows.

[image]

[image]

```
def verticalProjection(img):
    "Return a list containing the sum of the pixels in each column"
    (h, w) = img.shape[:2]
    sumCols = []
    for j in range(w):
        col = img[0:h, j:j+1] # y1:y2, x1:x2
        sumCols.append(np.sum(col))
    return sumCols

def slice_digits(image_name):
    img = cv2.imread(image_name, 0)
    bw = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
    env = verticalProjection(bw)
    env = np.asarray(env, dtype=np.float32)
    #filtered = moving_average(img)
    peaks,_ = signal.find_peaks(env, width = 5)
   # print(peaks)
    plt.scatter(peaks, env[peaks]   ,  s=50, c='r')
    plt.plot(env)

    plt.show()
```

Comment: If you already compute the peaks, just check for those peaks which have the same y-coordinate

Comment: @TA but the peaks are not detected sometimes which are marked by the arrow.. so those peaks with same height can not be detected, so I need another solution ?

Comment: @TA If I get the peaks, how would I filter the peaks that has the same height ?

Comment: If you are able to plot the peaks, you should have the coordinates of each peak for your plot. The y-coordinate of your peak should correspond to its height.

Comment: I think I need to get the DC component of the image, how would I get that... The peak term is missing.. I would like to get the```_```letter...